# Need some clarification on running Cassandra nodetool repairs

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, nodetool

So we've been having trouble balancing our workload on our current cluster, due mainly to budgetary constraints and the inability to add more nodes at this time.  Up until recently, having a node go down overnight was happening frequently, so I was frequently running nodetool repair.  Recently the cluster has become more stable and these downed nodes aren't happening regularly, so last weekend I created cron jobs for the nodetool repair -pr on each node to be run on a weekly basis.  The gc_grace is still at default 10 days, and the max hints is still at the default of 3 hours.

My questions are:

1. If we lose a node for longer than 3 hours, what exactly happens to the hint/s?  Does it/they no longer exist?
2. If we lost a node for longer than the 3 hours but for some reason didn't realize that the node had been down that long, what will happen if the nodetool repair -pr is run rather than the full repair on the downed node?
3. How would you fix the issue/s from question 2 if that is in fact the case?
4. Is there a way to check that all nodes are significantly consistent/repaired?

This hasn't happened yet (at least I don't think so), but I'm trying to plan ahead for the worst case scenario since our cluster stability may or may not lost longterm so I'd rather be prepared as I possibly can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) If we lose a node for longer than 3 hours, what exactly happens to
>   the hint/s? Does it/they no longer exist?

Yep that's right, your hints will get deleted (tombstoned) and they will go away through the regular compaction process. You can actually see this for yourself, just select from the `system.hints` table.

Check out our [docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__max_hint_window_in_ms) and [Jonathan's blog post on HH](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/modern-hinted-handoff).

> 2) If we lost a node for longer than the 3 hours but for some reason
>   didn't realize that the node had been down that long, what will happen
>   if the nodetool repair -pr is run rather than the full repair on the
>   downed node?

For the period in between that node coming back up and your running repair, you might be saving stale data.

`-pr` means you just repair the primary ranges on that machine. If you're running repairs with -pr across your cluster, you'll still be repairing everything.

Rather than using chron, I recommend you try out the [OpsCenter repair service](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__max_hint_window_in_ms) which automates this process.

> 3) How would you fix the issue/s from question 2 if that is in fact
>   the case?

A repair will get you back to the baseline of full consistency which is why you should be running it weekly (or in < gc_grace).

> 4) Is there a way to check that all nodes are significantly
>   consistent/repaired?

Only way is to build Merkel Trees which is what repair does. You might as well repair once you find the inconsistency. No way to just compare without repairing.

**NOTE**: Nice hints improvements coming in 3.0 check out this post by Aleksey:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-coming-to-cassandra-in-3-0-improved-hint-storage-and-delivery